# Can't install tensorflow in Docker on Silicon mac

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, apple-silicon

I want to install tensorflow in Docker on M1 Mac.

I have this error when `RUN pipenv lock`

```
#13 3.637 CRITICAL:pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.factory:Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
```

I simply set tensorflow='*' and python is 3.8, but it cant' find the `tensorflow` I just wonder,,, it is because on silicon mac?? or in my understanding docker file is independent from CPU, is it correct?

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.8
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY .. .
COPY .env.local .env
COPY Pipfile.local Pipfile
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv lock
RUN pipenv install --system

RUN chmod +x entrypoint.local.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.local.sh"]
```

`Pipfile.local`

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]

tensorflow = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.8"
```

error log

```
#13 0.679 Creating a virtualenv for this project...                                                                                
#13 0.679 Pipfile: /usr/src/app/Pipfile                                                                                            
#13 0.689 Using /usr/local/bin/python3.8 (3.8.13) to create virtualenv...                                                          
⠴ Creating virtual environment...created virtual environment CPython3.8.13.final.0-64 in 366ms                                     
#13 1.128   creator CPython3Posix(dest=/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-lp47FrbD, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
#13 1.128   seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/root/.local/share/virtualenv)
#13 1.128     added seed packages: pip==22.0.4, setuptools==62.1.0, wheel==0.37.1
#13 1.128   activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator
#13 1.128 
#13 1.188✔ Successfully created virtual environment! 
#13 1.497 Virtualenv location: /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/app-lp47FrbD
#13 1.512 Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
#13 1.513 Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
⠙ Locking..✘ Locking Failed! 
#13 2.493 
#13 2.493 CRITICAL:pipenv.patched.notpip._internal.resolution.resolvelib.factory:Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
#13 2.493 [ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 822, in _main
#13 2.493 [ResolutionFailure]:       resolve_packages(
#13 2.493 [ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 771, in resolve_packages
#13 2.493 [ResolutionFailure]:       results, resolver = resolve(
#13 2.493 [ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 751, in resolve
#13 2.493 [ResolutionFailure]:       return resolve_deps(
#13 2.493 [ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 1068, in resolve_deps
#13 2.493 [ResolutionFailure]:       results, hashes, markers_lookup, resolver, skipped = actually_resolve_deps(
#13 2.493 [ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 862, in actually_resolve_deps
#13 2.493 [ResolutionFailure]:       resolver.resolve()
#13 2.493 [ResolutionFailure]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pipenv/utils/resolver.py", line 663, in resolve
#13 2.493 [ResolutionFailure]:       raise ResolutionFailure(message=str(e))
#13 2.493 [pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure]: Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
#13 2.493   You can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
#13 2.493   Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
#13 2.493 ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
#13 2.493
```

Comment: I believe it is [this issue](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2619) (Pipenv is confused by the naming conventions). Does removing it from your `Pipfile` and adding `pipenv install --verbose https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-2.6.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl` to your `Dockerfile` work?

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried  `tensorflow-2.8.0-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_14_x86_64.whl` and `tensorflow-2.8.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl` however both shows the same error `is not a supported wheel on this platform`

Comment: maybe try cp38 instead of 39, since you're on Python 3.8?

Comment: @Josh Friedlander I tried cp38 but still same error.

Comment: I tried three versions `linux x86` , `macos x86, `win amd64` but all shows the same error.. I am wondering that I am now using docker linux image on silicon mac. so,,, my environment is maybe linux_arm,,, so there is no image???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your issue and was able to build the image using an explicit URL for a generic image: `RUN pipenv install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.9.0-py3-none-any.whl` and removing `tensorflow` from the Pipfile. This is a pipenv issue and not related to your CPU arch, AFAIU.

Comment: Thank you very much ! `RUN pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.9.0-py3-none-any.whl` works for me, it installs the `1.9` but it solves the main problem. I need to find the way to install version more than 2 though.

Comment: where can we find these kind of wheel urls?

Comment: [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/+/r0.10/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#pip-installation) is a list, for an old version. I think Docker is probably the best way to go nowadays though

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your platform in your Dockerfile

```
FROM --platform=linux/arm64 python:3.8
...
```

Comment: I try this but `failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: dockerfile parse error line 5: FROM requires either one or three arguments` some arguments is are wrong?

Comment: I can build the project with , `docker build -f Dockerfile .  --platform=linux/amd64` and install is successfully. However I need some amd64 machine to run this images.

Comment: I've edited my answer.  The platform flag needs to come before the base image name.  You may need platform specific images for different platforms.  I have had a lot of issues running the x86_64 version of tensorflow on apple silicon--the arm64 versions seems to resolve a lot of these. You can build both arm64/amd64 images at the same time using docker buildx https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/

Comment: @whitebear you can still run the image on your M1 Mac, but it will use an emulation layer for amd64 and will probably be noticeably slower. It may also crash due to qemu.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use tensorflow in Docker on an M1 (ARM) Mac, and don't want to rely on a wheel compiled by a third party, [this](https://medium.com/@schultz-christian/how-to-run-tensorflow-in-docker-on-an-apple-silicon-mac-c56f3127b696) is how you build the wheel yourself (see also the [repo](https://github.com/Christian-Schultz/tensorflowbuilder)).